# When I use storm trident，how can I manully fail a bolt and make the spout re-emit the tuple?

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I've tried many ways, but I find some exceptions cannot make the spout re-emit. But in my work, I strongly need that, how can I do?
I've tried to throw the FailedException, but it seemed useless. This is my code

```html
 try { 
process.waitFor(); 
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
throw new FailedException(e); 
}
```

Comment: did you try throw new FailedException("..")?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but it didn't work. This is the code       
                try {
                    process.waitFor();
                  
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new FailedException(e);
                }

Comment: You should edit your question instead of putting this additional information into a comment -- this keeps the question clean and easy to read. Nobody want to read all the comments.

Comment: OK, thx for your advise:)